# Hiding content with jQuery, after a time period specified with an HTML class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I am trying to hide some content after a specific time, with JavaScript / jQuery parsing the class list to figure out the time. To make it more clear, I'm giving these examples:

```
<div id="one" class="some-class some-other-class timeout-3500"> </div>
<div id="two" class="another-irrelevant-class timeout-2000"> </div>
```

The script should hide `div` "one" after 3500ms, and `div` "two" after 2000ms.

My code so far, combining the jQuery library with vanilla JavaScript, is as follows:

```
$('div[class*="timeout-"]').each(function()
{
    var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);

    var timeoutDelay;

    for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++)
    {
        if (classList[i].includes('timeout-'))
        {
            timeoutDelay = parseInt(classList[i].split('-').pop(), 10);

            setTimeout(function()
            {
                $(this).hide();
            }, timeoutDelay);
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a (non-working) fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/56o57t0j/.

The `setTimeout` fires, but `$(this).hide();` does nothing. It's like nothing is selected with jQuery (which of course isn't true, since all the code is inside a selector block with `each()` appended).

Any help with this? It has been troubling me since the morning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `this` inside `setTimiout` is `window`. Wrap `setTimiout` call into a closure.

Comment: You should use a data attribute, no parsing of a classname is needed

Comment: For reference, see [The "this" problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#The_this_problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your timeout function with the correct scope.  Scope and binding is a fairly advanced topic in JS that can be confusing at first, but since the "timeout" is being executed asynchronously, it is actually executed outside the scope of the parent "each" loop.  Therefore, "this" is not known at the time of execution.  If you bind the function like below, it will work:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).hide();
}.bind(this), timeoutDelay);
```

I have forked your fiddle with a working example:  https://jsfiddle.net/jg7m6cyu/1/

MDN has a great article on how "bind" works.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0):

The problem is setTimeout is called in different context then the function. So the "this" in setTimeout is not the same "this" in the function. So copying it to a variable "that" saves the function context.

```js
$('div[class*="timeout-"]').each(function() {
  var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
  var timeoutDelay;
   //need to lexically bind this because setTimeout is a different calling context
  var that=this;
  for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
    if (classList[i].includes('timeout-')) {
      timeoutDelay = parseInt(classList[i].split('-').pop(), 10);

      setTimeout(function() {
        $(that).hide();
      }, timeoutDelay);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Tahoma", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-class some-other-class timeout-3500">
  First div.
</div>
<div class="yet-another-div with-some-class timeout-2000">
  Second div.
</div>
```

Comment: Inside the loop `that` changes with each iteration ;(

Comment: Thanks, didn't pay attention to the fact that they are looping through the classes to get the timeout

Comment: `that` still change inside `$(...).each` loop. ;(

Comment: wouldn't you need that so that you can have different timeouts for each div, $(this) would also be different, correct?

Comment: `timeoutDelay` is a value, `this` (or `that`) is a reference to a object. This makes difference.

Comment: I just saw your solution, I understand now, use an iife and pass the this into, also don't know why the downvote.

Comment: OP has two loops, `$(...).each` which works with elements (`this` is an element inside the loop) and internal `for` loop which manages classList to calculate `timeoutDelay`. See approved answer or my answer how to manage `this` and `timeoutDelay`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use the data attribute, something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="one" class="some-class some-other-class delayed" data-timeout="3500"> </div>
<div id="two" class="another-irrelevant-class delayed"  data-timeout="2000"> </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('div.delayed').each(function()
{   
    var timeoutDelay = $(this).data('timeout'),
        el = $(this);

    setTimeout(function()
    {
        el.hide();
    }, timeoutDelay);
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ybbwg8ee/)

Comment: Using a data attribute is a great suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

In OP `this` inside `setTimiout` is `window`. Wrap `setTimiout` call into a closure.
This code will work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++)
{
    if (classList[i].includes('timeout-'))
    {
        timeoutDelay = parseInt(classList[i].split('-').pop(), 10);

        (function(elem,timeout){
           setTimeout(function()
           {
               $(elem).hide();
           }, timeout);
        })(this,timeoutDelay); //this comes from $(...).each
    }//if
}//for
```